# How do I use cfchart area type to show comments per time period

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2012, coldfusion-10, cfchart

I'm trying to create an area chart using cfchart, but not sure how to go about it. I'm doing a query of all comments in a table and want to show time period (days or months on x-axis) and output number of comments as they are created. Here's the comment query:

```
<cfquery name="qGetComments" datasource="#session.datasource#">
SELECT PersonFirstName
       , PersonLastName
       , PersonZip
       , CommentCode
       , refTopicID
       , tbComment.CommentID
       , tbComment.CreateDateTime
FROM tbPerson 
JOIN tbComment ON tbPerson.PersonID = tbComment.PersonID
</cfquery>
```

From here, I'm not sure the values to put in the cfchart to output the area chart the way I want. Something like this?

```
<cfchart chartWidth="400" show3D="yes"> 
    <cfchartseries type="area" query="qGetComments" 
       valueColumn="CommentID" 
       itemColumn="CreateDateTime" /> 
</cfchart>
```

Comment: (Edit) *show comments per time period* Then you need an aggregate query. Specifically one that incorporates a `count(...)` and groups by some date interval you select (by day, month, ecetera). That will involve date functions, which are often database specific. So 1) what date interval ? 2) What is your DBMS and version?

Comment: You might also want to look at using the native ZingChart library instead of `cfchart`. I have found that using the native library is often times easier than using `cfchart` in ColdFusion 10. The ZingChart website has a 'chart builder' that allows you to generate the JSON for a certain type of chart with a certain type of formatting. You can take that JSON and use it as a foundation for what you need to do.

Comment: Hey @leigh I'm using SQL Server. Grouping by day would be perfect. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Which version, 2005, 2008, ..? Though there are standards, syntax varies by version as well (so it is always good to include both in question tags).

Comment: @Leigh sorry about that 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to group the records by date in Server 2008+ above is cast the `datetime` column to a `date`.  Then use simply use the "CommentDate" column as the chart item and "NumOfComments" for the value:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, tbComment.CreateDateTime) AS CommentDate
      , COUNT(*) NumOfComments
FROM  tbPerson INNER JOIN tbComment ON tbPerson.PersonID = tbComment.PersonID
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, tbComment.CreateDateTime);
```

You can make the chart labels a little more user friendly by formatting the date within the SQL (see [cast and convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)). Just be sure to order the results by the `date` value, and not the formatted *string*. Otherwise, the chart labels may not appear in proper chronological order (it is a common mistake):

```
--- format as:  Mon dd, yyyy
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbComment.CreateDateTime, 107) AS CommentDateString
      , COUNT(*) NumOfComments 
FROM  tbPerson INNER JOIN tbComment ON tbPerson.PersonID = tbComment.PersonID 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbComment.CreateDateTime, 107) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbComment.CreateDateTime, 107), 107)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77973/13)

As an aside, if HTML charts are an option, you might look into Scott's suggestion. Generally `CFChart` is fine for *simple* cases, but once you start to customize the appearance (which invariably happens), you are usually better off using the underlying tools directly.